# Pandas, Filling between dates with average change between previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

I think this is best illustrated with examples. Lets say we have a DataFrame like such:

```
                 295340      299616
2014-11-02   304.904110  157.123288
2014-12-02   597.303413  305.488493
2015-01-02   896.310372  454.614630
2015-02-02  1192.379580  599.588466
2015-02-04  1211.285484         NaN
2015-03-02          NaN  726.622932
```

Now let's say I want to reindex this, like such:

```
rng = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])

df.reindex(rng)
                 295340      299616
2014-11-02   304.904110  157.123288
2014-11-03          NaN         NaN
2014-11-04          NaN         NaN
2014-11-05          NaN         NaN
...

2014-11-29          NaN         NaN
2014-11-30          NaN         NaN
2014-12-01          NaN         NaN
2014-12-02   597.303413  305.488493
```

Now if we look at 295340, we see the difference between their values is (597.30-304.90) = 292.39.

The amount of days between the two values is 31. So the average increase is 9.43 a day.

So what I would want is something like such:

```
                 295340      299616
2014-11-02   304.904110  157.123288
2014-11-03   314.336345         NaN
2014-11-04   323.768581         NaN
2014-11-05   333.200816         NaN
```

The way I calculated that was:

```
304.904110 + (((597.303413-304.904110) / 31) * N)
```

Where N is 1 for the first row since row 1, 2 after, etc.

I would obviously want all the columns filled this way, so 299616 with the same method and such.

Any ideas for something that is as efficient as possible? I know of ways to do this, but nothing seems efficient and it seems like there should be some type of fillna() or something that works for this type of finance related problem.

NOTE: The columns will not all be spaced out the same. Each one can have numbers anywhere within the range of dates, so I can't just assume that the next number for each column will be at X date.

Comment: For starters, check out ```resample()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) with the `"time"` method after a `resample`.  (It won't give quite the numbers you gave, because there are only 30 days between 2 Nov and 2 Dec, not 31):

```
>>> dnew = df.resample("1d").interpolate("time")
>>> dnew.head(100)
                 295340      299616
2014-11-02   304.904110  157.123288
2014-11-03   314.650753  162.068795
[...]
2014-11-28   558.316839  285.706466
2014-11-29   568.063483  290.651972
2014-11-30   577.810126  295.597479
2014-12-01   587.556770  300.542986
2014-12-02   597.303413  305.488493
2014-12-03   606.948799  310.299014
[...]
2014-12-30   867.374215  440.183068
2014-12-31   877.019600  444.993589
2015-01-01   886.664986  449.804109
2015-01-02   896.310372  454.614630
[...]
2015-02-01  1182.828960  594.911891
2015-02-02  1192.379580  599.588466
[...]
```

The downside here is that it'll extrapolate using the last value at the end:

```
[...]
2015-01-31  1173.278341  590.235315
2015-02-01  1182.828960  594.911891
2015-02-02  1192.379580  599.588466
2015-02-03  1201.832532  604.125411
2015-02-04  1211.285484  608.662356
2015-02-05  1211.285484  613.199302
2015-02-06  1211.285484  617.736247
[...]
```

So you'd have to decide how you want to handle that.